# How to redirect sys log of ubuntu running on virtual machine to host?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, vmware

I have ubuntu installed on my VM(Vmwarefusion - version 7) running on my Mac book Pro. I am actually doing kernel development by writing kernel modules on ubuntu. If have a kernel crash, sometimes my vm is stuck and i have no way going back to terminal and viewing system logs using dmesg command. The only option left is rebooting the system and I have lost sys log which have dmesg output most of the times. So is there any way I could actually redirect sys log output to my host i.e my Mac Pro so that when I have kernel panic, I can go and look them.

Comment: Check out `man 5 syslog.conf` how to redirect logs to a remote host.

Comment: Related:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/53910/how-can-i-receive-syslog-logs-from-a-networked-system
http://askubuntu.com/questions/186592/how-do-i-configure-rsyslog-to-send-logs-from-a-specific-program-to-a-remote-sysl?s=2|2.9358

Comment: You can also tell the kernel to log over a serial line, which the VM host can usually pick up and do whatever it likes with.